# Search and read the file name in C

Tags: c, file, fileinfo

I have a scenario where I want to search my directory for all the files which have ".ip" in their filename and then read the filenames(I don't need to open the file). I also need the time-stamp for each files and store them. I am using a Linux system and would like the solution to be in C.

Here's what my directory looks like:

```
 MyFolder/Data
   ── server.linux.config
   ── linux.115.65.45.123:9000.ip
   ── windows.54.34.105.192:3050.ip
   ── local.127.0.0.1:8080.ip
   ── server.bin
   ── keys.bin
```

For example, I need to need to read the filename "linux.115.65.45.123:9000.ip" since it has "ip" in its file name and get ip_address "115.65.45.123", port no. "9000", system "linux" after reading the name and then the time-stamp of the file ( 2021year 10month 25day 14hour 37min 25sec).

Here by timestamp I mean when the file contents were last modified(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second).

Comment: Solutions could be very different in C and C++. For example, C++ have [the filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) with nice classes to iterate over directories. Please only tag one language, and then the language of which you have made *your own* attempt.

Comment: Also be aware that questions can be closed for needing _more focus_ if you haven't yet decided what language you are using.  A "C or C++" question requires an answer that would work in "C or C++", which may prove difficult to provide.

Comment: Start by showing *every* file in the folder, and refine it to filter just the matching names.

Comment: Start with [`glob(3)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html)?

Comment: Why a compiled program? You can do this with `ls -l *.ip` in your shell.

Comment: What do you mean by "the time-stamp"?

Comment: @Drew Dormann, I have changed the focus. It would like the solution in C.

Comment: a possible strategy would be glob for list of filenames, stat for  timestamps,  and use regex to get Ip and port number.  Also they have to be valid ip addresses., regular expressions can validate it

Comment: There is no one solution for any of this, especially mixing C and C++. Take a look at `stat` for file metadata and regex libraries for parsing strings by patterns. https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat | https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: @sweenish , it's a small part of the another program I am working on right now.